# PHP function to get the number of all pages posted by a certain user id

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to retrieve from db the total number of pages written by a certain user using the below code:

```
function getPagesNoById($id) {
    if ($id) {
        $sql_query = "SELECT COUNT(page_id) FROM `texts` WHERE `user_id` = '" . $id . "'";
        $query = mysql_query($sql_query)or die(mysql_error());
        $cnt = mysql_num_rows($query);
        mysql_close($conn);
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        return $result;
    }
    return false;
}

print getPagesNoById(7);
```

But the result is empty. Is there something wrong with it ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: @marc-b as i said the code isnt running with or without the quotes so i dont see any relevance of why you have marked as duplicate as the main question is other!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
function getPagesNoById($id) {
    if ($id) {
        $sql_query = "SELECT COUNT(page_id) FROM `texts` WHERE `user_id` = '" . $id . "'";
        $result = mysql_query($sql_query) or die(mysql_error());
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        $total = $row[0];
        return $total;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(page_id) FROM ...
```

Don't use the '-char in MySQL for column selection - 'is constant'. For this use the `-char  or nothing as long there is no whitespace or any other special char in your colname...

Comment: Tried also $sql_query = "SELECT COUNT(page_id) FROM `texts` WHERE `user_id` = '" . $id . "'"; . The same empty.

Answer (score 0):

try to change,

```
 $sql_query = "SELECT COUNT('page_id') FROM `texts` WHERE `user_id` = '" . $id . "'";
```

to

```
 $sql_query = "SELECT COUNT(page_id) FROM `texts` WHERE `user_id` = '" . $id . "'";
```

and also remove

```
  mysql_close($conn);
```

in the middle

Comment: Tried the same empty response. In php my admin : SELECT COUNT(page_id) FROM `texts` WHERE `user_id` = '7'; returns 93